# Nativescript performance with custom components

Tags: nativescript

Let's say I have a Nativescript Vue component that looks like this:

```
<template>
    <GridLayout columns="auto, auto">
        <TextField col="0" />
        <Button col="1" />
    </GridLayout>
</template>
```

I would like to use this component for example 10 times in a form. As far as I know using the component like this would be rather inefficient in nativescript.
For the performance it would be better to not use a custom vue component and just create a component with one GridLayout that contains the above components 10 times.
I mean something like this:

```
<template>
    <GridLayout rows="10" columns="auto, auto">
        <TextField row="0" col="0" />
        <Button row="0" col="1" />
        <TextField row="1" col="0" />
        <Button row="1" col="1" />
        ...
    </GridLayout>
</template>
```

With a custom component it would look like this:

```
<template>
    <GridLayout rows="10" columns="auto, auto">
        <CustomComponent row="0" />
        <CustomComponent row="1" />
        ...
    </GridLayout>
</template>
```

which would translate to:

```
<template>
    <GridLayout rows="10" columns="auto, auto">
        <GridLayout row="0" columns="auto, auto">
            <TextField col="0" />
            <Button col="1" />
        </GridLayout>
        <GridLayout row="1" columns="auto, auto">
            <TextField col="0" />
            <Button col="1" />
        </GridLayout>
        ...
    </GridLayout>
</template>
```

In this case I have only one GridLayout instead of 11 with the custom component. Using a custom component would be a lot more convenient though.
I could easily tweak the component and don't have duplicate code. I also can do animations with `ref` more easily (not giving each Label/Button a unique name etc.).

I wonder if the second approach is the best one could do if you want better performance? Is there a way to achive the same performance with custom components?

Answer (score 0):

Using custom Vue components are never a issue but it's all about how your design and what layouts you use. There are two simple ways you could retain the performance here,

1. **Choose right layout:** Instead of using GridLayout with 10 rows, you should consider using a StackLayout. GridLayout is good when you have known number of limited partitions. When you just want to stack items one after another you must go with StackLayout.
2. **Use ListView / RadListView:** The more UI elements you add to screen, the main / UI thread becomes heavy and looses responsiveness. It's not just with NativeScript, but even with native apps. You must consider using ListView / RadListView with one or more item templates as needed. The component has its own logics to reuse the views (item templates) as you scroll down / up. You should not use Id / Ref with this component as the templates will be reused as needed, so prefer playing with data, binding class names etc.,

Comment: About your first suggestion: I don't see how that would improve performance. Instead of using `<GridLayout rows="10" columns="auto, auto">` I just use `<StackLayout>`. Sure StackLayout might be the better layout here but I'd still have the other 10 GridLayouts.
About your second suggestion: How am I supposed to do animations when I can't use `ref`?

Comment: The first suggestion is not about number of elements but how the layout and measurement system works. We have different layouts for a reason, StackLayout is one designated for stacking items. There is a nice [video presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U191esT9_zY) done by Brad Martin, that might help you understand.